# Dynamically change a db in transact sql

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, ssrs

I am trying to run a script against a database that is dropped from a third party daily so the name of the database changes daily.  I can get the name of the new database using the sys.databases folder but I am trying to populate it into an SQL statement.  I am hoping to get this to run and move it into SSRS.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: You'll probably need to use dynamic SQL, i.e. declare a variable of type nvarchar(max) and assign your DML statement with the proper database name to that variable. Use sp_executesql to run it. Note that it doesn't have to remain a dynamic statement; you can create views and stored procedures that way too.

Comment: @dartonw you may not want to us sp_executesql since that will end up needlessly caching the statement in  the plan cache.  EXEC (@cmd) may be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use dynamic SQL to change the DB you are executing the query in:

```
DECLARE @dbname AS VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @query AS VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @dbname = name
FROM sys.databases d
WHERE /*enter criteria here to get DB*/

SET @query = '
use ' + @dbname + '
/*enter your query here*/
'

PRINT @query
EXEC(@query)
```

Comment: Perfect answer but for security reasons (SQL Injection) and to pootentially increase performance (caching of the plan), please use sp_executesql instead of just EXEC().  https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql

Comment: Caching the plan may or may not be helpful.  If each statement is only ever ran once, caching it is a waste of resource.